# Load Test - Jmeter PreProcessor

Tags: jmeter

I have a preprocessor that creates random uuid and random string as below

```
import java.util.UUID;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils;

String testId1=UUID.randomUUID().toString();
String testId2=RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(10);

vars.putObject("testId1",testId1);
vars.putObject("testId2",testId2);
```

the test plan is created as below
[image]
The post anomaly uses the above ids in the payload. The first time when the script is run the testId1 and testId2 in the request is coming as `${testId1}` and `${testId2}`

when I run this test for few samples in GUI i see these variables are  generated. I run this test in distributed mode and I found from one server the testId1 and testId2 are generated but not from other.(Non GUI mode) what would be the issue here?

Comment: There is no issue with your code. Can you try with `vars.put("testId1",testId1);
vars.put("testId2",testId2);`. Have you defined these variables in somewhere elese too?

Comment: No I have not used this variable elsewhere .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is "the issue" on the "other server" you will find the reason in `jmeter-server.log` file on that server. Normally JMeter prints sufficient amount of troubleshooting information to its [log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), it's extremely useful especially when a JSR223 PreProcessor fails somewhere somehow.

Log verbosity can be increased for either particular components of for the whole JMeter application, see [How to Configure JMeter Logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) article for more details.

---

Remember that you should avoid scripting and stick to JMeter's built-in test elements where possible, in your case you can generate both variables using [__UUID()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__UUID) and [__RandomString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) functions